# Html hexadecimal function parameter unexpectedly being converted to decimal.

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, hex

I am calling this function from an html onclick listener with a parameter which is a hex number representing an address, but the output is the same number represented in decimal form. I tried converting back but it rounds the hex number. Why does the function call convert the hex number in the first place?

```
flexcard += '<button class="mod marg" onclick="App.fundProject('+thisProjectAddress+')">Fund project</button>';
```

Comment: What is the hexadecimal number and the text of `App.fundProject` function?

Comment: there's no number at all in your snippet. But in general, JS knows only numbers and doesn't care what format you use to "describe" the number. If you need the sequence of characters to stay as it is, you should use a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `thisProjectAddress` is defined in your code without quotes, it's being interpreted as a hex number instead of a string and thus will generally be represented as its decimal counterpart. For example:

```js
console.log(0x100) // => 256
console.log("0x100") // => 0x100
```

Furthermore, even if it is being stored as a string, you're writing it into `flexcard` as an argument to `App.fundProject` without quotes. This means this bit of `flexcard` will probably look like this:

```
<button class="mod marg" onclick="App.fundProject(0x100)">Fund project</button>
```

Since, as with the first example, the hex number is being passed without strings, it's interpreted as a number, and the function will deal with it appropriately. Whatever output `App.fundProject` has involving its argument will treat it the same as if you had passed `256` instead of `0x100`. If you want it to be kept in its hexadecimal representation, pass it as a string instead of a number:

```
flexcard += '<button class="mod marg" onclick="App.fundProject(\''+thisProjectAddress+'\')">Fund project</button>';
```

Which will produce this output instead:

```
<button class="mod marg" onclick="App.fundProject('0x100')">Fund project</button>
```

Comment: If you want to convert the content of a String into its proper literal representation, you should use `JSON.stringify()` and not just wrap it in some quotes. In this special case `"0x100"` there is no difference in result, but it is a practice that eventually *(with some seemingly unrelated update)* will introduce errors in your app due to not properly escaped characters. Just sayin; I've had to learn that the hard way.